# Using Javascript How to loop through a div containing checkboxes and get the value checked from each check box

Tags: javascript

I have a table with each row containing a cell that has 8 check boxes(Column4)

Here is an example

```
   <table id="enc-assets" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th><th>Column4(CONTAINS OPTIONS)</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>

        <td id="sc-isrc"></td>
        <td id="sc-filename"></td>
        <td id="sc-path" hidden></td>
        <td id="sc-platforms">
            <div id="sc-inline" style="display: inline-block;">
                <div >
                    <div ng-repeat="p in products ">
                        <label id="enc"><input id="Platform" ng-checked="prod[p.name]"  ng-model="prod[p.name]" ng-init="prod[p.name] = true" type="checkbox"/></label>                                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td><br/><br/><button id="enqueuebtn"  type="button" ng-click="Show(test)" class="btn-primary"></button></td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to loop through each row and assign values from each cell into an object .

I am having problems getting the value checked from the cell that contains the 8 check boxes. I can get values from the other cells just fine.

I have tried the following:

```
$("#enc-assets tbody tr").each(function() {
  var message;
  message = new Object();
  message.isrc = $(this).find('#sc-isrc').text();
  message.path = $(this).find('#sc-path').text();
  $("#sc-platforms div div").each(function() {
    var platform, selected;
    selected = $(this).find('#Platform div label input').checked;
    if (selected === true) {
      platform = $(this).find('#enc').text();
```

This is the part that I am not sure if works:

```
  selected = $(this).find('#Platform div label input').checked;
```

Do I have the correct nesting here to get the values from the check boxes?

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique within the whole document. If you try to match different objects with the same id, you won’t get multiple results. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dNvtz/)

```
$("#enc-assets tbody tr").each(function() {
    var message;
    message = new Object();
    message.isrc = $(this).find('#sc-isrc').text();
    message.path = $(this).find('#sc-path').text();
    $("#sc-platforms>div>div").each(function() {
        alert( $(this).attr('id') );
        var platform, selected;
        selected = $(this).find('#Platform');
        if(selected.is(':checked')) {
            alert('Checked');
        }
        platform = $(this).find('#enc').text();
        alert(platform);
    }); //END each #sc-platforms>div>div
}); //END each #enc-assets tbody tr
```